# Text on Image Mouseover - CSS Positioning

Tags: css

I am using this fork code to display text on mouseover of an image.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hxqoe

HTML

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/150" alt="some text" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/150" alt="more text" />
<img src="http://placekitten.com/150" alt="third text" />

<div id="text"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

img:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('img').hover(function() {
   $('div').html($(this).attr('alt')).fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
   $('div').html('');
});
```

I am looking for the `div` text to be displayed inside each image instead of a stationary `div`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need jQuery for this. It can easily be achieved with pure CSS.

In this example, I use the `:after` pseudo element to add the content from the `alt` attribute of the parent `div`. You can add whatever styling you want..

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2nfgj/) - Updated to include a fade

**HTML** - pretty simple

```
<div alt="...">
  <img src="..."/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div:after {
    content: attr(alt);
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border: 10px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s all;
    -webkit-transition: 1s all;
    -moz-transition: 1s all;
}

div:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: thank you Josh - i like this approach - the only drawback is that you don't have a nice fade-in / fade-out effect for the text.. Is this something we can add to your solution ?

Comment: also is the :after pseudo element compatible with older browsers?

Comment: @JoannaMikalai Sure - just use CSS transitions and adjust the opacity. http://jsfiddle.net/2nfgj/

Comment: @JoannaMikalai If you have any questions - let me know :)

Comment: great thanks Josh - i think I should be ok with everything - thanks for the help !

Comment: Hey Josh, there is a bug with the code.. When i hover the mouse to an empty area below the picture, i can see the box appearing.. any ideas?

Comment: @JoannaMikalai Interesting - it doesn't do that in the example... Can you provide something demonstrating this?

Comment: Please look at this image: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v158/neodjandre/photo_07Nov030221.jpg

Comment: i need to invite you to my private beta - how can i do this? I also created a fiddle with my exact code but the problem doesn't show up there.. http://jsfiddle.net/qmc4E/8/

Comment: @JoannaMikalai I'm not really sure what to say since I can't see the glitch.. however, I do have a random solution that might work. Add `display:inline-block` and `overflow:hidden` to the parent.. That will force it to contain the children elements.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai It was just a random guess :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to this:

```
$('img').hover(function() {
   $('div').html($(this).attr('alt')).fadeIn(200);
   $('div').css('left',$(this).offset().left + 'px');
   $('div').css('top',$(this).offset().top + $(this).height() - 20 + 'px');
}, function() {
   $('div').html('');
});
```

And that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your images in some kind of wrapper and then use CSS for the hover effect ([**DEMO**](http://cdpn.io/udsyi)).

HTML:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/150" alt="some text 1" />
  <div class="img-desc">some text 1</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.img-desc {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.6;
  padding: 5px;
}

.img-wrapper:hover .img-desc{
  display: block;
}
```

I added an alternative solution with additional css transition to the demo.

To get a transition just control the visibility with `opacity`:

```
.img-desc {
  /*...*/
  opacity: 0;
  /*...*/
}

.img-wrapper:hover .img-desc{
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
}
```